# Getting the right MANIFEST.MF file?

Tags: java, manifest

I've been trying to get the correct manifest file for a while now. When I try to get the manifest file it always gets the one from an API I'm using.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the manifest file from my own JAR file?

Comment: Every jar on the classpath with will likely have a `MANIFEST.MF` file. You will need to iterate through all of them and find the one you want...

Comment: "It", do you mean eclipse?

Comment: I think you'll have to provide some more information for people to be able to give a sensible answer